# Reactjs/Nextjs onClick event not working for external component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a main page, with a button component i create to reuse in my project. My issue is when i add the onClick event to my external component, the click event is not working, but is i create the same button inside my main page, the click event works just fine

**Button Component**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const BigButton = (props): JSX.Element => {
    return <>{props.red ? <BigBtn red={props.red}>{props.val}</BigBtn> : <BigBtn>{props.val}</BigBtn>}</>;
};

export default BigButton;

const BigBtn = styled.button`
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 78px;
    height: 30px;
    background: ${(props) => (props.red ? "#BD2129" : "#2e3034")};
    border: ${(props) => (props.red ? "initial" : "1px solid #494b4f")};
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
`;
```

**This works on main page**

```
<button onClick={buttonClose}>Close</button>
```

**Button Component on main page - This doesn't work on main page**

```
<BigButton val="Cancel" onClick={handleClose} />
```

**Close function**

```
const handleClose = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.onClose();
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component does not look correct. You do not have `button` inside the component and `onClick` event. You should update like this

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const BigButton = (props): JSX.Element => {

const handleClick = () => {
            props.onClick()
    }
    return <>{props.red ? 
                    <BigBtn red={props.red}>
              <button onClick={handleClick}>
                  {props.val}
              </button>
            </BigBtn> : 
              <BigBtn>
                <button onClick={handleClick}>
                  {props.val}
                </button>
              </BigBtn>}
           </>
};

export default BigButton;

const BigBtn = styled.button`
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 78px;
    height: 30px;
    background: ${(props) => (props.red ? "#BD2129" : "#2e3034")};
    border: ${(props) => (props.red ? "initial" : "1px solid #494b4f")};
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
`;
```